# Creating a new matrix using vectorization in R

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices 'times' and 'scaleFactor'. Each row in the 'times' matrix represents a person and the column represents the time at which some event occurred. The event changes the scale-up factor, which is available in the 'scaleFactor' matrix. For e.g., for person 1, the factor would be 1.2 in the time interval (1,3].

I want to create a matrix C having factors at each integer time point, where first column is time=0. I have written the code for generating matrix 'C', but I was wondering whether the 'for' loop can be avoided because the actual matrix is very large.

```
scaleFactor <-  matrix(c(1,1.1,1.2,1.4,
                         1,1.3,1.4,1.6,
                         1,1.2,1.6,2.1),nrow = 3,ncol = 4, byrow = T)

times <- matrix(c(0,1,3,99,
              0,2,5,99,
              0,1,4,99),nrow = 3,ncol = 4,byrow = T)

> scaleFactor
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1  1.1  1.2  1.4
[2,]    1  1.3  1.4  1.6
[3,]    1  1.2  1.6  2.1
> times
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    3   99
[2,]    0    2    5   99
[3,]    0    1    4   99

C <-  matrix(0,nrow = 3,ncol = 6)

for (i in 1:ncol(C)){
  indices <- max.col(i-1<=times,'first') 
  C[,i] <- scaleFactor[cbind(1:3,indices)]
}

> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1  1.1  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
[2,]    1  1.3  1.3  1.4  1.4  1.4
[3,]    1  1.2  1.6  1.6  1.6  2.1
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Edit: I later realized that the 'times' matrix can have non-integer time values. For such cases, the approach suggested by akrun works. Thanks!

```
times2 <- matrix(c(0,1.2,3.6,99,
                  0,2.1,5.3,99,
                  0,1,4,99),nrow = 3,ncol = 4,byrow = T)

> times2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0  1.2  3.6   99
[2,]    0  2.1  5.3   99
[3,]    0  1.0  4.0   99

# Matrix C would be -
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1  1.1  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
[2,]    1  1.3  1.3  1.4  1.4  1.4
[3,]    1  1.2  1.6  1.6  1.6  2.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method by `rep`licating in pure `Vectorized` code

1. We `rep`licate the sequence of column from C (subtracted 1) with the `length` of 'times'
2. Do the comparison on the `t`ransposed 'times'
3. Convert to a `matrix` to create `dim` attributes
4. Apply `max.col` to get the column index for max value per row
5. Then, `cbind` with the row index
6. Get the corresponding 'scaleFactor' value based on the row/column index from 5
7. Assign the output back to C with `[]` so that the matrix attribute is preserved

```
C[] <- scaleFactor[cbind(1:3, max.col(matrix(rep(seq_len(ncol(C)) - 1,
     each = length(times)) <= c(t(times)), ncol = ncol(times), 
      byrow = TRUE), "first"))]
```

-output

```
C
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1  1.1  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
[2,]    1  1.3  1.3  1.4  1.4  1.4
[3,]    1  1.2  1.6  1.6  1.6  2.1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use a trick using `rep` and `asplit` (splits an array into a list of vectors, handy here).

```r
C <- t(
  mapply(rep, asplit(scaleFactor,1),
         times = asplit(cbind(1, t(apply(times, 1, diff))), 1))
)
dim(C)
# [1]   3 100
C[,1:8]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1  1.1  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.4  1.4
# [2,]    1  1.3  1.3  1.4  1.4  1.4  1.6  1.6
# [3,]    1  1.2  1.6  1.6  1.6  2.1  2.1  2.1
```

Its stability depends on the last column of `times` being equal (so that all people iterate for the same number of time periods).

This works by first converting `times` (which are the time period when something changes) to "duration" (number of days in each column), with

```r
cbind(1, t(apply(times, 1, diff)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    2   96
# [2,]    1    2    3   94
# [3,]    1    1    3   95
```

From there, we use these numbers as the `times=` argument for `rep`. To keep the dimensions correct, we do this independently for each person, which is why we need to split the matrices up by row using `asplit(., 1)`:

```r
asplit(scaleFactor, 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.4
# [[2]]
# [1] 1.0 1.3 1.4 1.6
# [[3]]
# [1] 1.0 1.2 1.6 2.1
```

We then pair the scale factors with the corresponding times into `rep`:

```r
head(
  rep(c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4), times = c(1, 1, 2, 96)),
  8)
# [1] 1.0 1.1 1.2 1.2 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4
```

In order to iterate this efficiently across all rows of both matrices at the same time, we `asplit` the matrices and feed them into `mapply`, which passed the first row of `scaleFactor` with the first row of our "duration" (`times` differenced), second row with second row, etc.

Comment: This approach works well when the 'times' matrix has integer values. However, I have a matrix with non-integer time values. In such cases, matrix C is not being correctly updated. I am not sure how to handle it. Thank you!

Comment: You said *"factors at each integer time point"* (and your data was integral), so it seemed safe to assume the times were always integral. Are you able to `round(.,0)` them to approximate what you need? If not, well, you got the answer to the question you asked but not what you need ... I suggest you should update your question with appropriate fractional `times` and updated expected-output if you hope to get something adapted to your real needs.